# Combining Points into Polygon in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcgis-pro

I have a map with thousands of points, one for each address in a particular city. The points are color-coded based on a feature of them, the school which students at that address attend.

I also have census tracks / block groups / blocks on the map.

I would like to add a layer to the map which is "school zones" - basically combining the points of the same color into a polygon.

How can I do this?

In particular, I would like to find a solution that can be implemented in ArcGIS Pro.

One approach I was thinking of was doing some kind of spatial join between the points and the small geographic areas from the census.

Comment: What about inevitable overlaps, if you just join up the points? What about conflicts if you use the small areas (surely not all contained addresses always visit the same school)?

Comment: I don't know, maybe assign the area a school based on what the most addresses within it go to? Otherwise, what do you suggest I do?

Comment: If you wish to ask the same question about ArcGIS Online then that should be done in a separate question. How far did you get when you tried to do this using ArcGIS Pro?

Comment: Not too far  - I'm not sure what the parameters of the spatial join should be.

Answer (score 1):

A different answer than you propose (because I dont know what you actual end goal is).
If you simply want to "view" many of these points, you can explore create a dot [density map](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/mapping/layer-properties/dot-density.htm). There's a [nice example here](http://cartonerd.blogspot.ca/2018/03/dotty-election-map.html), using election data by Ken Field.

If you want to actually parse the data, take a look at the [Summarize Within](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/summarize-within.htm) tool. It sounds like it might be what you want based on your input datasets.